# How to plot an area figure for a category variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here are two reproducible minimal examples for my request.

1. In the first one, the `x` variable is a factor variable, I find the function `geom_area` does not work, works like a `geom_segment` output.
2. In the second one, I transfer the `x` variable from factor into interger, the function `geom_area` works but I find the `axis.text.y` labels are not what I want.

Anyone know fix it?

```
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))
mtcars %>% 
    rownames_to_column('index1') %>% 
    mutate(index1 = index1 %>% as.factor) %>% 
    mutate(index2 = index1 %>% as.integer) -> df

df %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_area(aes(x = index1, y = mpg), color = 'black', fill = 'black') +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

```
df %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_area(aes(x = index2, y = mpg), color = 'black', fill = 'black') +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: looks like two issue's..should it not be two separate questions? Also, take a look at `long` and `wide` data format's..perhaps that could be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(wrapr)

df %.>% 
  ggplot(data = .) +
  geom_area(aes(x = index2, y = mpg), color = 'black', fill = 'black') +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = .$index2,
    labels = .$index1
  )
```